# SuiteScript2.0 Working with timeofday fields

Tags: suitescript2.0

I am trying to enter a value for a timeofday field using SuiteScript2.0 but I keep getting an error.

"type\":\"error.SuiteScriptError\",\"name\":\"INVALID_FLD_VALUE\",\"message\":\"You have entered an Invalid Field Value 1:00 pm for the following field: somerandomfieldid\"

I tried the following,

- 1:00PM
- 1:00 PM
- 1:00 pm
- 13:00

None of these seem to work for this field type.
What is the correct format for time fields.

Answer (score 0):

The any date/time fields for 2.0 need to be in in a Date object.

you can use for `format` module to format the string to the correct format.

```
format.parse({value, type , timezone?});
```

value is your date/time value;

type is the equal to the type of the field;

timezone is optional, but it will set the timezone of the server;

The format module will return a date on success, and string no failure, at least from my experience. 
The format module only accepts correctly formatted string for the field type, like for me time has to be `h:mm a`, and date has to be `m/d/yyyy`

you can use `util` module to check if the value from `format` module is date.